# Android application theme style

Tags: android

Can someone guide me through the application theme. I have read so much about it but still I cant get through it. Everywhere in stackoverflow answers its mentioned as AppBaseTheme and AppTheme. Which one do I mention in application manifest as the APPLICATION THEME. Secondly How do i change my actionbar background color?

Comment: have you tried any of the option that you're specifying about.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   </style>
```

Comment: yes i tried this one. But still its not working. and how do i change the background of my action bar?